# Web Push notification without icon - chrome

Tags: push-notification, web-push

When I send notification without icon it looks like this:
[Web push without icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9yR3.png)

Json:

```
{"title":"Example notification", "options":{"body":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent scelerisque ligula velit, in luctus sem varius eu. Maecenas efficitur sem in maximus"}}
```

How to get rid of an empty space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always include the icon. You cannot get rid of the empty space.

Comment: I can not find such information in the any documentation!

Comment: @dodobusko General practice is to include the icon (i.e. it's like saying that a favicon is not mandatory - it's not mandatory but you should include it because it is general practice). And in any case you cannot customize the layout of web push notifications.